# JMSTemplate "sessionTransacted" behavior while sending non-persistent messages to ActiveMQ broker

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, spring-integration, jmstemplate

I want to understand behavior(sync or async) of transacted sessions in spring JMSTemplate while sending non-persistent messages to the ActiveMQ broker. 
I am talking about the **JMSTemplate** configuration where **Session is transacted and messages sent are non-persistent**

According to my understanding:
The non-persistent messages send to the ActiveMQ broker are sent async. 
But messages send on a transacted session are synchronous. Since commit call is synchronous and JMSTemplate commit after each message sent.

Is message sending with the above specified configuration is synchronous or asynchronous? Please help me to understand this behavior.

Thanks,

Anuj

Answer (score 1):

The persistence is irrelevant - the commit is a separate operation on the session.

Comment: So irrespective of persistent or non-persistent, the messages sending in a transacted sessions will be synchronous (because commit is synchronous and JMSTemplate commit the session after each message is sent)?

Comment: Thanks Gary. Does persistent messages send in a transacted session will have two level of synchronization? First since it is persistent, so sending of messages will be blocked until the message is consumed by the broker. And another is transacted session commit call.

Comment: That's a function of your broker and it's client library but, typically, no, the send won't block, only the commit.

Comment: I am using ActiveMQ as the message broker. "If I send a batch of persistent messages in a transaction, the message sending will be asynchronous. Only commit is synchronous."                          Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I believe so, but I don't know ActiveMQ internals; why don't you run a WireShark trace to confirm?